# Change column value based on kV of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, and I actually need to make a comparison (>= 110) or (<110) on the kilovoltage indicated in the column A.
Then if kv >= 110, change the value of column C to Transmission.
If kc < 110, change the value of column C to Distribution.
Default value if there is no number is Distribution.
But only if the column B is "sampletext"
I precise that the comparison can only be done onthe kV, there can be other numbers in the string but they are not important.

here is what the dataframe like (I have other column in beetween, so I need to refer to the column by name).

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lorem ipsum 400kv | sampletext | distribution |
| lorem 400 kV ipsum | sampletext | distribution |
| lorem 32 ipsum 109KV loremipsum | sampletext | distribution |
| lorem ipsum | sampletext | generation |

here is what the data should look like

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lorem ipsum 400kv | sampletext | transmission |
| lorem 400 kV ipsum | sampletext | transmission |
| lorem 32 ipsum 109KV loremipsum | sampletext | distribution |
| lorem ipsum | sampletext | generation |

I tried putting some example of case to show that the kv is not always written the same way and at the same position.
The regex to find the kilovoltage is this one if I'm not wrong :

```
(\d+)(\s|.)((?i:kv))
```

I tried to use conditions, .extract, .contains or even np.select, but I just can't find how to make it work.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Note that your described logic and the shown example do not really match, I've assumed you want to replace the value is C if kV>=110 or kV<100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with `(?i)(\d+)\s*kv`, then convert to number with [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = pd.to_numeric(df['A'].str.extract(r'(?i)(\d+)\s*kv', expand=False))
df.loc[s.lt(100)|s.ge(110), 'C'] = 'transmission'
```

Output:

```
                                 A           B             C
0                lorem ipsum 400kv  sampletext  transmission
1               lorem 400 kV ipsum  sampletext  transmission
2  lorem 32 ipsum 109KV loremipsum  sampletext  distribution
3                      lorem ipsum  sampletext    generation
```

Comment: Thank you, it work wonderfully and it's easy to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

i don know exact your logic.is this what you want?

```
import numpy as np

s = df['A'].str.extract(r'(?i)(\d+)\s?kv')[0]
out = df.assign(C=np.select([s.ge('110'), s.lt('110')], ['transmission', 'distribution'], default=df['C']))
```

`out`

```
    A                                   B           C
0   lorem ipsum 400kv                   sampletext  transmission
1   lorem 400 kV ipsum                  sampletext  transmission
2   lorem 32 ipsum 109KV loremipsum     sampletext  distribution
3   lorem ipsum                         sampletext  generation
```

Answer (score 0):

try (\d\d\d ?(kv|kV|KV|Kv))

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['lorem ipsum 400kv',
'lorem 400 kV ipsum',
'lorem 32 ipsum 109KV loremipsum',
'lorem ipsum'], 'B': ['SampleText','SampleText','SampleText','SampleText',], 'C': ['distribution','distribution','distribution','distribution',]})

for i in range (len(df)):
    try:
        reg_ex = re.search(r'(\d\d\d ?(kv|kV|KV|Kv))', df['A'][i])
        condition_regex = re.search(r'\d\d\d',reg_ex.group())
        con_ = condition_regex.group()
        if int(con_)>=110:
            df['C'][i] = 'transmission'
        else: 
            continue
        
    except:
        continue

print(df)
```